# TiKZ won't graph 1/sqrt(x)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Evening!

Posting a quick message here cause I have a small problem with TiKZ. I've been trying to plot the function 1/sqrt(x), and it just... won't work.

Here is the code I've been typing:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1]
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:100,
    xscale=1,yscale=1,
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax= 1,
    samples=10000,
    axis lines=center,
]
    \draw[thick, samples = 1000, blue] plot[domain=0:100] ({\x, 1/sqrt(\x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But here's what I get:

[image]

I tried with other functions, still have problems. 
For example, if I just plot sqrt(x), here's what I get:

[image]

At least, the shape is now right... but the values are completely off.

So if anyone should have any idea on how to correct that code, I'd be really grateful, thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! `1/sqrt(\x)` has a singularity at 0 and should fall for larger `\x`. But the technical reason why it does not work is that you set the braces wrongly, `(\x,{ 1/sqrt(\x)})` is correct but still has the singularity.

Comment: Possibly the values are off too because you didn't specify the (correct) `\pgfplotsset`compatibility (which is why it's important to provide a fully functional MWE ;).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Diagram of the function `1/sqrt(x)` is the following:

[image]

In your MWE you have mix of `pgfplots`and plain `tikz` syntax. Better is stick to just one of them. For example to `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}% <-- changed
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    ymin=0, ymax=1,
    axis lines=center,
            ]
    \addplot [thick, domain=0:100, samples=100] {1/sqrt(\x)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the comments above, the syntax was incorrect. Since you seem to be using `pgfplots`, here is the way to do it. I exclude the singularity, and in `pgfplots` there is no need to put a backslash before `x`. Also I reduced the number of samples.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1]
\begin{axis}[domain=0:100,
    xscale=1,yscale=1,
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax= 1,
    samples=501,
    axis lines=center,
]
    \addplot[domain=0.0001:100] {1/sqrt(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for both your answers. Both work really well, I really appreciate it. Have a nice evening!